# How to create a custom installer for my game for PC/Linux/Macs?

Tags: linux, macos, pc, installer

How can I create a custom installer that integrates a product key unlocking feature or tells the distributor that the customer was able to access the product like the BMT Mirco payment processor. Or possible how can I connect my BMT Micro management to unlock products to install them in a custom installer.

I want it to have an easy setup like Inno Setup or Clickteam Install Creator and incorporate customized head/side banner.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can use the [Wix Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/). It allows you to do everything you want, but you need to spend a bit of time learning how to use it.

Comment: What language or toolkit is this? (HTML5 games are trivially portable. 70s [Lisp machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine) assembler, less so.)

Comment: I think this is straying too far into the "what technology should I use" area, but I think it's fair to ask this in the context of DRM and payment.  Since the process of installing the files itself can be implemented with anything, I suggest restructuring the question to focus on the DRM side of things.

Comment: @Boreal Sorry for the stray I am new to these forums, I'll restructure the question then.

Comment: @Anko I am not sure what you mean by toolkit, but the language my game is made in is Python